# Area constraint blows up my physics simulation if a body slams into it too fast

Tags: c#, .net, xna, constraints, physics

I have a physics simulation and it allows you to place area constraints, so that the bodies within will not exit that area. However if an atom goes past one of the "walls" of the area constraint it blows up the physics simulation. Why does it do this?
Update method:

```
if (!atom.IsStatic)
{
    Vector2 force = Vector2.Zero;
    bool x = false, y = false;
    if (atom.Position.X - atom.Radius < _min.X)
    {
        force = new Vector2(-(_min.X - atom.Position.X), 0);
        if (atom.Velocity.X < 0)
            x = true;
    }
    if (atom.Position.X + atom.Radius > _max.X)
    {
        force = new Vector2(atom.Position.X - _max.X, 0);
        if (atom.Velocity.X > 0)
            x = true;
    }
    if (atom.Position.Y - atom.Radius < _min.Y)
    {
        force = new Vector2(0, -(_min.Y - atom.Position.Y));
        if (atom.Velocity.Y < 0)
            y = true;
    }
    if (atom.Position.Y + atom.Radius > _max.Y)
    {
        force = new Vector2(0, atom.Position.Y - _max.Y);
        if (atom.Velocity.Y > 0)
            y = true;
    }
    atom.ReverseVelocityDirection(x, y);
    if (!atom.IsStatic)
    {
        atom.Position += force;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on "blows up"?  Exception?  Incorrect results?

Comment: All non-static atoms just disappear and i suspect have their positions set to NaN.

Comment: You suspect they have their positions set to NaN? How's about using the debugger and checking for sure?

Comment: Confirmed. It is becoming NaN.

Comment: BTW, atom.Position.X - atom.Radius < _min.X -- here (and down) I think the condition should be <= -- i.e. when atom "touches" the border it's time to reverse the movement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you know, after about half an hour of mindless hacking at it, i thought of simply not applying the position correction. That fixed it like a charm. For any interested, here's the updated code:

```
if (!atom.IsStatic)
{
    if (atom.Position.X - atom.Radius < _min.X && atom.Velocity.X < 0)
    {
        atom.ReverseVelocityDirection(true, false);
    }
    if (atom.Position.X + atom.Radius > _max.X && atom.Velocity.X > 0)
    {
        atom.ReverseVelocityDirection(true, false);
    }
    if (atom.Position.Y - atom.Radius < _min.Y && atom.Velocity.Y < 0)
    {
        atom.ReverseVelocityDirection(false, true);
    }
    if (atom.Position.Y + atom.Radius > _max.Y && atom.Velocity.Y > 0)
    {
        atom.ReverseVelocityDirection(false, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: See my note about epsilon in my message too. May be that's the cause of your original problem.

Comment: Ugh, I was hoping you would actually have a solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

I see you're doing calculation with a constant time step T. When modeling collisions though *on every step* you should use time step equal to minimal time before any of atoms reach any obstacle.

Make time step variable, and atoms will never "tunnel" obstacles.

P.S. There are a lot of optimizations in collision detection, please read gamedev papers for information on those.

**P.S. A bug?**

```
force = new Vector2(-(_min.X - atom.Position.X), 0);
```

Force is created separately for X and Y reflection. What happens when the atom gets into a corner? Only second force will be applied.

**P.P.S: Use epsilon**

One more important note: if you use floating point, the error is accumulated, and you should use eps:

```
abs(atom.Position.Y + atom.Radium - _max.Y) < eps
```

where eps is a number much smaller than normal sizes in your task, e.g. 0.000001.

Comment: I use a verlet integration with a constant timestep, plus i was advised to not use a timestep when calculating constraint satisfaction.

Comment: Good point though i don't think that's the root cause of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have solved the problem already, but I notice that "force" seems to be wrong. It moves the atom *away* from the boundary, even if it's on the wrong side. Suppose an atom has shot past _max.X:

```
if (atom.Position.X + atom.Radius > _max.X) 
    { 
        force = new Vector2(atom.Position.X - _max.X, 0); 
        ...
    }
```

Now "force" will be in the +x direction, and the atom's distance from the wall will double with every iteration. Boom!

Comment: oh man it's that simple? Why didn't i see it? Thanks for spotting the error!